# Migrating tomcat war to JBoss

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, struts2, jboss

I have redeployed tomcat web application struts war to jboss 5.1.
It's showing successfully deployed, but when i am accessing my home page of web application it's giving an error i.e.

```
               ERROR [[jsp]] Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
               java.lang.ClassCastException:   org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade cannot be cast to javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
                at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:73)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
                at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
                at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
                at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
                    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
                    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
                    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
                at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
                    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: I believe it is just a matter of upgrading your servlet api in war to match servlet api 2.5 which is the default that is supported by jboss 5.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure that jboss uses its own servlet-api.jar and not any other one. If you are packaging the servlet-api.jar in your war file then simply remove it and try.

Comment: I am using struts framework, Where to find this library? I am looking in WEB-INF/lib. there i have many struts2 and some other jars.

Comment: @AshishKataria is there servlet jar in WEB-INF/lib?

Comment: No, there is one javax.jar and many others, but not any with servlet name

Comment: @AshishKataria Ok do one thing, just remove all the jars which are there in jboss server lib from your appliction WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: @Juned.. u mean removing all jar's from WEB-INF/lib which are common with jboss server lib?

Comment: servlet import is javax.servlet.http, and i have javax.jar added..After removing it, i am getting missing definitions of servlets.

Comment: Thanks.. that error is resolved... but still is there anything to change when migrating tomcat struts war to jboss?